# Show files on Wikipedia that were recently added to a specific category

Tags: wikipedia

On Wikipedia, is it possible to view all of the files or articles that were recently added to a specific category? In this case, I want to view all files that were recently added to `[[Category:Birds]]`, and show the files in descending order of recency.

Comment: "Recency" is indeed an English word, according to my spell-checker. It's not a neologism. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that. That's why I created a service called Category Watchlist that periodically monitors categories from Wikimedia wikis you ask it to and reports changes to them.

For more information, see [the tool's description page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aSvick/CW) and [the site of tool itself](http://svick.org/CatWatch.aspx).